# error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'TCHAR *'

Tags: c++, c++14

In a multibyte project (vs2017):

```
#ifndef _TCHAR_DEFINED
typedef char            TCHAR;
typedef char *          PTCHAR;
typedef unsigned char   TBYTE;
typedef unsigned char * PTBYTE;
#define _TCHAR_DEFINED

struct _getopt_data
{
    /* These have exactly the same meaning as the corresponding global
       variables, except that they are used for the reentrant
       versions of getopt.  */
int optind;
int opterr;
int optopt;
TCHAR *optarg;

/* Internal members.  */

/* True if the internal members have been initialized.  */
int __initialized;

/* The next char to be scanned in the option-element
   in which the last option character we returned was found.
   This allows us to pick up the scan where we left off.

   If this is zero, or a null string, it means resume the scan
   by advancing to the next ARGV-element.  */
TCHAR *__nextchar;

/* Describe how to deal with options that follow non-option ARGV-elements.

   If the caller did not specify anything,
   the default is REQUIRE_ORDER if the environment variable
   POSIXLY_CORRECT is defined, PERMUTE otherwise.

   REQUIRE_ORDER means don't recognize them as options;
   stop option processing when the first non-option is seen.
   This is what Unix does.
   This mode of operation is selected by either setting the environment
   variable POSIXLY_CORRECT, or using `+' as the first character
   of the list of option characters.

   PERMUTE is the default.  We permute the contents of ARGV as we
   scan, so that eventually all the non-options are at the end.
   This allows options to be given in any order, even with programs
   that were not written to expect this.

   RETURN_IN_ORDER is an option available to programs that were
   written to expect options and other ARGV-elements in any order
   and that care about the ordering of the two.  We describe each
   non-option ARGV-element as if it were the argument of an option
   with character code 1.  Using `-' as the first character of the
   list of option characters selects this mode of operation.

   The special argument `--' forces an end of option-scanning regardless
   of the value of `ordering'.  In the case of RETURN_IN_ORDER, only
   `--' can cause `getopt' to return -1 with `optind' != ARGC.  */

enum
{
    REQUIRE_ORDER, PERMUTE, RETURN_IN_ORDER
} __ordering;

/* If the POSIXLY_CORRECT environment variable is set.  */
int __posixly_correct;


/* Handle permutation of arguments.  */

/* Describe the part of ARGV that contains non-options that have
   been skipped.  `first_nonopt' is the index in ARGV of the first
   of them; `last_nonopt' is the index after the last of them.  */

int __first_nonopt;
int __last_nonopt;

#if defined _LIBC && defined USE_NONOPTION_FLAGS
    int __nonoption_flags_max_len;
    int __nonoption_flags_len;
# endif
};

int
_getopt_internal_r(int argc, TCHAR *const *argv, const TCHAR *optstring,
    const struct option *longopts, int *longind,
    int long_only, struct _getopt_data *d, int posixly_correct)
{
 ... 
 TCHAR c = *d->__nextchar++;
 TCHAR *temp = _tcschr(optstring, c); // <= cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'TCHAR *' (first parameter) 
 ...
}
```

Everything looks correct; in tchar.h:

```
#define _PUC    unsigned char *
#define _CPUC   const unsigned char *
#define _PC     char *
#define _CRPC   _CONST_RETURN char *
#define _CPC    const char *
#define _UI     unsigned int


/* String functions */

__inline _CRPC _tcschr(_In_z_ _CPC _s1,_In_ _UI _c) {return (_CRPC)_mbschr((_CPUC)_s1,_c);}
```

Why is _tcschr() complaining that a parameter is not of const char*, when it is?

Comment: _tcschr is complaining that it's not of type `TCHAR*`. Not `const char *`!

Comment: please include the compiler error message in the question, don't paraphrase it

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @ idclev 463035818 updating question/

Comment: oh I just realized that the error message is in the title. The title is to summarize your question. Important information should be in the question too

Comment: @ n. 'pronouns' m. One sec

Comment: You can not convert a `const char *` to a `TCHAR *` (a.k.a `char *`) as this removes the `const` attribute from the pointer.

Comment: Side note: TCHAR was a solution to Microsoft having two  operating system lines, one using ANSI characters and the other unicode, back at the end of the last millennium. The need for it pretty much came to an end when Windows XP squashed all competition. This raises the question, why, more than 15 years later, are you inflicting this suffering on yourself?

Comment: It isn't obvious from the snippets, but Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language > Conformance mode = No is useful to keep old code alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, [`_tcschr()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strchr-wcschr-mbschr-mbschr-l?view=msvc-160) is overloaded to take either a `TCHAR*` or a `const TCHAR*` as input.  To return a non-const `TCHAR*`, you will have to call the non-const overload, which means casting away the `const` off of `optstring`, eg:

```cpp
TCHAR *temp = _tcschr(const_cast<TCHAR*>(optstring), c);
```

Or else define `_CONST_RETURN`, per the documentation:

> In C, these functions take a `const` pointer for the first argument. In C++, two overloads are available. The overload taking a pointer to `const` returns a pointer to `const`; the version that takes a pointer to non-`const` returns a pointer to non-`const`. The macro _CRT_CONST_CORRECT_OVERLOADS is defined if both the `const` and non-`const` versions of these functions are available. If you require the non-`const` behavior for both C++ overloads, define the symbol _CONST_RETURN.